# When two open-front vowels meet, does one become, typically, weaker?

Tags: pronunciation, stress-reduction

. . . at last [ət-lӕst] . . [[audio source]](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/141)

I guess, from the two lots’ pronunciations, that when [ӕ] is accompanied by [ӕ], one which is lesser important in meaning becomes weaker and change into a schwa sound. Is this a typical pattern?

Comment: But *last* is pronounced /lɑːst/. /æ/ is used in a word like *flat*. Or are we talking of American pronunciation or some other non-standard form?

Comment: The change in the vowel has nothing to do with two front vowels coming together, and everything to do with *at* being an unstressed syllable in *at last*. Nobody weakens either of the vowels in *rat trap*.

Comment: @PeterShor  Incorporate that into an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Those two vowels are not in any way “meeting”: they have two different consonant phonemes intervening between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change in the vowel in *at last* has nothing to do with the fact that two open-front vowels are near each other. Nobody weakens the vowels in *rat trap*, another phrase with two /ӕ/ vowels. The reason the vowel is weakened in *at last* is that the word *at* is unstressed.

Vowels in unstressed syllables in English are often reduced, meaning they change into a /ə/. In the phrase *at last*, and in many similar phrases (*at odds, at most, at least*), the word *at* is unstressed, and the vowel tends to be reduced to /ə/. You can see that in *at odds* and *at most*, the two vowels are not both open front; yet the vowel in *at* is still weakened.

Comment: In ordinary rapid speech, only stressed vowels are unreduced. Everything else gets centralized, usually to an allophone of /ə/.

Comment: @John: Right, but I didn't want to bring up secondary stress in my answer (i.e., the second syllable of *"rattrap"*).

Comment: Stress is stress; if it keeps the vowel from centralizing, that's good enough.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603199/2085).